# Solidworks 2011 SolidCAM crash

Tags: windows, debugging, crash, crash-reports, solidworks

*The situation*

At work, we use Solidworks to develop 3d models of products we make. Besides Solidworks we use the addin SolidCAM to calculate machine times that will be sent to production.

*The problem*

When loading the SolidCAM files (.PRZ and .PRT) the program will crash every now and then (approx. every half hour). Resulting in reopening everything in the state it was last saved. So in total this will happen around 10-15 times each day with  all users that work with these files.

*What i've done so far*

I sat with one of the users that experiences these crashes and found that with each crash it generates a .log and .dmp file. The .log file isn't telling me much, but the .dmp file at least shows me something is going wrong with SLDWORKS.exe. Any idea what is causing this crash? If you need any information, feel free to ask away. Here is the content of the file

```
FAULTING_IP: 
HostLibSW!OnSWHRTBUpdate_ShowToolTbl+14318
00000000`03195298 488b4840        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rax+40h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000003195298 (HostLibSW!OnSWHRTBUpdate_ShowToolTbl+0x0000000000014318)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 000000000fab6870
Attempt to read from address 000000000fab6870

PROCESS_NAME:  SLDWORKS.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - De instructie op 0x%08lx verwijst naar geheugen op 0x%08lx. Een lees- of schrijfbewerking op het geheugen is mislukt: %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - De instructie op 0x%08lx verwijst naar geheugen op 0x%08lx. Een lees- of schrijfbewerking op het geheugen is mislukt: %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000000fab6870

READ_ADDRESS:  000000000fab6870 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
HostLibSW!OnSWHRTBUpdate_ShowToolTbl+14318
00000000`03195298 488b4840        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rax+40h]

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

MANAGED_BITNESS_MISMATCH: 
Managed code needs matching platform of sos.dll for proper analysis. Use 'x64' debugger.

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000003193e77 to 0000000003195298

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffffffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STACKIMMUNE

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NOSOS_INVALID_POINTER_READ

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 sldworks.exe+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  sldworks.exe

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: sldworks

IMAGE_NAME:  SLDWORKS.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4e86dbff

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE_c0000005_SLDWORKS.exe!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NOSOS_INVALID_POINTER_READ_sldworks.exe

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/SLDWORKS_exe/19_5_0_91/4e86dbff/HostLibSW_dll/1_0_0_1/4cc4d6dd/c0000005/00125298.htm?Retriage=1
```

Comment: Contact SOLIDCAM. They're the only ones that can interpet the error file. I think these crashes occur because of some faulty SOLIDWORKS API call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the graphics card is using the correct certified driver
2. Untick the SolidCAM addin, do you still get crashes?If the crashes only occur when SolidCAM  is added in then you are best contacting SolidCAM, it could be a servicepack issu
3. Rename the registry key current user\software\solidworks and also \solidcam if there is one and restart SW